# I'm not receiving firebase notifications on my iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I installed this plugin to display notifications in my flutter application: [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

On android, everything works fine. I receive notifications when I'm outside the app and when it's open.

But on IOS nothing works. I've followed several tutorials on YouTube and reread the documentation several times too.

This is my AppDelegate.swift file:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

This is the file I call to display notifications:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:nezrouge/src/constants.dart';
 
class LocalNotificationsServices {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
 
  static void initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/ic_stat_logo");
 
    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestAlertPermission: true,
    );
 
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);
 
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
 
  static void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "pushnotification",
      "pushnotificationchannel",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      color: primaryColor,
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
      channelShowBadge: true,
    );
 
    const DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails();
 
    final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
    const NotificationDetails notificationsDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: iosNotificationDetails,
    );
    await notificationsPlugin.show(id, message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body, notificationsDetails);
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart :

```dart
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:nezrouge/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:nezrouge/src/notifications/notification_manager.dart';
 
import 'src/app.dart';
 
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
 
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
 
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
  LocalNotificationsServices.initialize();
 
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
 
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: true,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: true,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
 
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
    (RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        LocalNotificationsServices.showNotification(message);
      }
    },
  );
 
  final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print(fcmToken);
 
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );
 
  runApp(
    MyApp(
      fcmToken: fcmToken.toString(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: have you enabled apple push notification from developers account by creating signing certificate?

Comment: Yes, I've created a certificate and everything needed.